# How can I use tcpdump on remote machine with sshdump?

Tags: ssh, wireshark, tcpdump

I'm using sshdump in my local machine for capturing traffic on remote machine. But there is issue for capturing remote machine. Firstly let me explain my setup.

A->It's my local machine

B->It's remote machine and accessible by A

C->It's another remote machine. It's accessible by B and **not accessible from A**.

Here I want to use sshdump to capture from A machine to C machine. I write ssh command for capturing remote machine like below.

[image]

But I got this error.

[image]

I want to capture traffic on C machine from B machine and read output from A.
Is there any way for this?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that. Firstly you need to establish tunnel with B machine from A machine and then you need to give below command to remote capture command. Then A machine  can listen to C machine.

ssh root@**C machine address** "tcpdump -U "not port 22" -i any -w -"